# App Store email address / Apple ID

Tags: apple-id

Whenever I go to my Apple Store it shows an the incorrect email (it show an email that is no longer active)
How do I get my iPhone 6s to show the correct email so I can update my apps?

Comment: Did you log out and log back with the other Apple ID already?

Comment: @Rob yes I have logged off and even reset the entire phone

Comment: The concept some people have trouble grasping is that iOS has like 7 places within "settings" where different AppleId's can be used at the same time. For example, iCloud, App Store, iMessage, FaceTime, mail, etc each of those could be different.

Comment: @Tyson - true enough. As someone who's had an iTunes ID since long before even me.com existed [though I was never a mac.com user] I've long since learned which is which - though roll on the day when they finally allow us to merge accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" Apple ID is the one used to purchase the apps originally.

It doesn't need to be tied to your current email address & in fact doesn't actually have to be an email address at all. You can change your primary email address associated with an Apple ID...

> ## [Change your Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/HT202667)
>
> Follow these steps to change the email address that you use as your Apple ID.
>
> 1. Sign out of [every Apple service and device](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204071) that uses your Apple ID.
> 2. Sign in to your [Apple ID account page](https://appleid.apple.com/).
> 3. In the Account section, click Edit. Under your Apple ID, click Change Email Address.
> 4. Enter the email address you want to use as your Apple ID. A verification code will be sent to your new email address.
> 5. Enter the verification code from the email into the fields provided and start using your updated Apple ID. [Didn't get the email?](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201455)
> 6. [Sign back in to all Apple services with your new Apple ID.](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204071)
>
> You can change your Apple ID to any other email address you control,
>   as long as it's not already in use as an Apple ID. If your email
>   address ends with @icloud.com, @me.com, or @mac.com, you might not be
>   able to change your Apple ID. You also won't see Change Email Address
>   on your account page.

Comment: it is not the apple Id it is app Store email that is incorrect.  So when I go to update my apps the incorrect email appears and even if I use the old password to that email address it will not move forward.

Comment: And to add - if you need the current email, and to sure that it is this email you see when an update is available, then delete the app, and download it again with your current Apple ID (email) - the old email is stored inside the app - which is a zip-fil with a lot of app sources.

Comment: The "app store email" **is** the Apple ID. If you are using multiple IDs then you need to sign out of the App Store then back in with the other ID.